# Trying to call a new aspx page through jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a new aspx page through jquery
Like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function dynamicForm() {           
        $("#openForm").click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $("#gvCustomers").hide();                
            var radioValue = $("input[name='optionsRadios']:checked").val();
            if (radioValue == 'uncoatedRdBtn') {
                window.location = "UncoatedWire.aspx";
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

but the page is showing blank with url "http://localhost:54327/UncoatedWire.aspx" .Any idea how to achieve it.

Comment: What happens when you browse the url directly in the browser?

Comment: Did you try to debug the project to see if the page is hit or not?

Comment: @xxxmatko yes it is going Uncoatedwire.aspx but whether it is going to page which i have already created or simply it is showing blank and created url

Comment: If you run your project on localhost you should see yellow screen with error if there is some. If you see just blank page when you open url "http://localhost:54327/UncoatedWire.aspx" then it is probably empty.

Comment: no it is empty.

Comment: any errors in browser's debugger console ?

Comment: @NitinSingh no errors

Comment: So you are telling that the page is empty, and than you are asking why it is empty?

Comment: in pageload, outside the postback, write "Response.Write("Hello world")"  then see if you can get this shown. Is the page controls created dynamically or is there some static content present.

Answer (score 0):

Try **window.open** it will open your request page on new browser window

```
window.open("UncoatedWire.aspx", "_blank", "WIDTH=1080,HEIGHT=790,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no");
```